# Debugging report error on SSRS

Tags: excel, templates, reporting-services, officewriter

we have a bunch of reports (RDL) on SSRS built using officewriter. Sometimes errors occur in a report after updating the excel template. While the report renders fine, an error occurs on the server when trying to save the report using 'export to excel format for office writer' option. How do we debug to find the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, i open the report directly on the report server & the detailed error shows up on the report.